# Problems installing electron js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron

**I am trying to install electronjs in node 18 lts and npm 10. But i get this error doing it.**

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator.GWNR71517\Desktop\electron> npm install electron --save-dev
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Administrator.GWNR71517\Desktop\electron\node_modules\electron
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node install.js
npm ERR! RequestError: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator.GWNR71517\Desktop\electron\node_modules\got\dist\source\core\index.js:970:111)
npm ERR!     at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:632:26)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:529:35)
npm ERR!     at origin.emit (C:\Users\Administrator.GWNR71517\Desktop\electron\node_modules\@szmarczak\http-timer\dist\source\index.js:43:20)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:501:9)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:517:28)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
npm ERR!     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
npm ERR!     at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Administrator.GWNR71517\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-02T17_54_10_674Z-debug-0.log
```

i tried visiting the official docs but it does not work

Comment: Your network connection being unreliable isn't really a programming problem.

Comment: i do not think it is a connection issue

Comment: ECONNRESET is usually a connection issue.

Comment: how can i fix it?

Comment: cause i do have internet and its not the best but it works for me